# Compairing html string to hex string with php

Tags: php, html, string, ascii, data-conversion

I am trying to compare two strings. When compared they are unequal to the computer. But to the human eye the strings appear to be the same.

When I run a test to check the bin2hex with php they are clearly unequal. Some how a set of double quotes is be read as html. Here are some examples:

```
 $string1 = strlen(html_entity_decode($_SESSION['pageTitleArray'][$b]));
 $string2 = strlen(html_entity_decode($value));

 echo 'Checking: ' . $_SESSION['pageTitleArray'][$b] . " " .  bin2hex($_SESSION['pageTitleArray'][$b]);
 echo '<br>';
 echo 'testing ' . $string1 . " = "bin2hex($string1) . " " . bin2hex($string2);
 echo '<br>';
 echo 'With: ' . $value . " " . bin2hex($value);
```

The code above will out put the following information.

> Checking: 1 PAIR OF BBC HEAD GASKET GASKETS MULTI LAYERED STEEL 4.585"
>   312050414952204f46204242432048454144204741534b4554204741534b455453204d554c5449204c41594552454420535445454c20342e35383522
>   testing 3630 3632 With: 1 PAIR OF BBC HEAD GASKET GASKETS MULTI
>   LAYERED STEEL 4.585″
>   312050414952204f46204242432048454144204741534b4554204741534b455453204d554c5449204c41594552454420535445454c20342e3538352623383234333b
>   false

I am kinda lost on what to do... Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the rest of the code so you can get a total feel for what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
     for($b = 0; $b < count($_SESSION['pageTitleArray']); $b++)
 {
   foreach($_SESSION['pushIdArrayQuery'] as $key => $value)
   {

     $string1 = strlen(html_entity_decode($_SESSION['pageTitleArray'][$b]));
     $string2 = strlen(html_entity_decode($value));

     echo 'Checking: ' . $_SESSION['pageTitleArray'][$b] . " " .  bin2hex($_SESSION['pageTitleArray'][$b]);
     echo '<br>';
     echo 'testing ' . $string1 . " = "bin2hex($string1) . " " . bin2hex($string2);
     echo '<br>';
     echo 'With: ' . $value . " " . bin2hex($value);

     if(trim($_SESSION['pageTitleArray'][$b]) == trim($value))
     {
       echo '<br>';
       echo '<h1>Success</h1>';
       echo '<br>';
       echo '<b>Key: </b>' . $key;
       echo '<br>';
       echo 'Page Id: ' . $_SESSION['pushTitleArrayQuery'][$key];
       echo '<br> ';
     }
     else {
       echo '<br>';
       echo 'false';
       echo '<br>';
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Look at what the characters actually are. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php You can `str_split` both strings then iterate over both arrays and see if the character codes are the same. https://3v4l.org/CSq5b You can use `char` after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed the problem. Notice, I removed any html attributes with the html_entity_decode() function. Then, from there I was able to strip away all other special characters by using preg_replace() and compare the results.

```
    //Loop through all the page titles from the directories
 for($b = 0; $b < count($_SESSION['pageTitleArray']); $b++)
 {
   //Loop through the page titles gathered from the database
   foreach($_SESSION['pushTitleArrayQuery'] as $key => $value)
   {
     //use html decode to remove the quotes with ENT_NOQUOTES
     $removeHtml =  html_entity_decode($value, ENT_NOQUOTES);

     //Test to make sure the encoding are the same for both variables. 
     $detectEncoding = mb_detect_encoding($value, "auto");

     //remove all non alphanumeric variables in the first string.
     $string1 = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_SESSION['pageTitleArray'][$b]);

     //remove all non alphanumeric variables in the second string.
     $string2 = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $removeHtml);

     //Print out to see what the results look like from decode and encoding functions
     echo 'Testing the removal of html quotes: ' . $removeHtml . ' Encoding: ' . $detectEncoding;
     echo '<br>';

     //Show what variables are being compaired. 
     echo 'Checking: ' . $string1 . " " .  bin2hex($_SESSION['pageTitleArray'][$b]);
     echo '<br>';
     echo 'With: ' . $string2 . " " . bin2hex($value);


     //If statement to check if the to strings match. 
     if(trim($string1) === trim($string2))
     {
       echo '<br>';
       echo '<h1>Success</h1>';
       echo '<br>';
       echo '<b>Key: </b>' . $key;
       echo '<br>';
       echo 'Page Title: ' . $_SESSION['pushTitleArrayQuery'][$key];
       echo '<br>';
       echo 'Page Id: ' . $_SESSION['pushIdArrayQuery'][$key];
       echo '<br> ';
     }
     else {
       echo '<br>';
       echo 'false';
       echo '<br>';
     }
     echo '<br>';
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different types of quotations mark (" on the first string and ″ on the second one).

To human eyes they seems similar but they are complete different characters to PHP.

Comment: Thank you @medrupaloscil! I would have never caught that.